# Using ImageMagick with zend_pdf

Tags: imagemagick, zend-pdf

How can I pass an image processed with ImageMagick (not saved) to Zend_Pdf_Image?
I want to transfer $image = new Imagick($imageFile); directly to $pdfImage = Zend_Pdf_Image:: ..., without saving. Is that possible?

Thanks for any advice,
Juergen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was about to simply say "no", but then I thought I would double-check the code and consider if there were any other possibilities.

The `imageWithPath()` method utilizes some helper methods in other classes to decode the image that is referenced by the `$filePath` parameter. The very first thing each of these helper methods does is open the `$filePath` using `fopen()`.

So what *that* means is that you can pass in any kind of resource to the `imageWithPath()` method that is supported by your PHP installation.

Generally speaking this means files and URLs, but since PHP 5.2 it also includes the `data://` wrapper. I haven't used this myself (I've been writing out temp files then passing them to `imageWithPath()` for years), but according to the man pages it might just enable you to pass in the modified data without having to save it to a file first.

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php

Please let us all know if you get something working using this method. :-)

Comment: James, thanks for this consideration. I solved it by saving the image and re-loading in Zend_Pdf. Kind regards, Juergen.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a code example. Maybe @Juergen does?

Answer (score 1):

I will just add my 3 cents to James answer above. He is perfectly right - it is allowed to use data: wrapper.

Example method showing how to convert svg to Zend_Pdf_Image using ImageMagick:

```
class My_Pdf extens Zend_Pdf {

    function imageFromSvg($path, $w, $h) {
        if (!class_exists('Imagick') || !file_exists($path)) return false;
        $svg = file_get_contents($path);
        $im = new Imagick();
        $im->readImageBlob($svg);
        $im->setImageFormat('png8');
        $im->adaptiveResizeImage($w,$h);
        return new Zend_Pdf_Resource_Image_Png('data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode   ($im));
    }
}
```

Note that Zend_Pdf_Resource_Image_Png doesn't support pngs with bit depth more then 8.
Returned object can be easily embeded in Zend_Pdf using its drawImage method. Example:

```
$pdf = new My_Pdf();
$page = $pdf->newPage(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
$page->drawImage($pdf->imageFromSvg($svg,400,400),400,100,100,100);
```

I used svg rescaled to 400x400, because I get better quality print then. You can experiment with this according to your needs.
Good luck!